# How do I Design and Interface (OOP kind) in Java so that I can either use direct database access or use web services?

Tags: java, oop, data-binding, interface

At the moment I have to query database that I do not own which has a web service, so what they provide is what I get.  Since this is in house (sort of), I might be able to get direct access in the future so that I can get better data in my query.

I don't want to have to write everything again and again.  If I did this in Java would I write an Interface (programming kind, think Implements Interface, OOP)?  How would I do this?  Or do I just write a whole new class and "plug it in."

This is just a regular client/server architecture.  Http request, server calls the servlet or jsp, returns data.

I'm not sure if my idea is correct design or not.

Comment: To add to what superEb said, you need to code it like the way getResultSet function works.
Its a method in the ResultSet interface in the jdbc package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely sounds like you should use an interface with different implementations here. Something like:

```
public interface DataAccess {
    Data getData();
}
```

Then you can code against this API and just plugin/inject a different implementation as needed. So you could have this:

```
public class DirectDataAccess implements DataAccess {
    public Data getData() {
        //use JDBC, ORM, or similar
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
public class WebServiceDataAccess implements DataAccess {
    public Data getData() {
        //call web service
    }
}
```

But as long as your client code only references the `DataAccess` interface, then you have successfully decoupled your client from your service.

Comment: Then I would just adjust the queries in the Interface?

Comment: The interface should only define the necessary parameters (argument types) and return type that is needed by your client (and will be common in your impls). The actual queries (e.g. SQL or HTTP request) should be defined in each specific impl, not in the interface.